# saving information into hash table or vectors

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to know which one is faster
hash table or vectors.

if I want to see loop over all the information inside and comparing it to my current data,
If it is already inside, I want to break my loop.

Example:

I have [{1,2},{1,2,3}] and  inside the loop my current new data is {1,2} (it is inside my vector or my hash table), so i will break my loop and  if i have {2,1} i will break it  too.

If all the elements matchs regardless the order I break otherwise i continue my loop. And if a hash table is much faster, Can I have a hint on how i can implement it because im new to C++

Comment: Did you post your question from a smart phone? No punctuation makes it hard to read.

Comment: sorry about that, i tried to rewrite it again, I hope it is better

Comment: Are vector and hash table the only choices?

Comment: no not at all ,but im new to C++ so don't know if there might be other options which are faster

Comment: If it matters, try both and see which one is faster. Measurement is much more certain than theorising. If it doesn't matter enough to you, write whichever one is easier to get right. (Correct but slow beats fast but wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

Hashtable will work better as you can create key value pair. The only condition is you should not have more than one combination where the key is same. So you cannot have 3,1 and 3,2 in the table as the key is unique.

If you have duplicates on lhs then best to use vector.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a nested set, that is, a `std::set<std::set<int> >`.

```
#include <set>
#include <cassert>

typedef std::set<int> Entry;
typedef std::set<Entry> Table;

int main () {
  int e1[] = {1,2};
  int e2[] = {1,2,3};
  int e3[] = {2,1};
  int e4[] = {3,2};

  Table t;
  t.insert(Entry(e1, e1+2));
  t.insert(Entry(e2, e2+3));

  Table::iterator it;
  Table::iterator end = t.end();;

  // Search for 1,2
  it = t.find(Entry(e1, e1+2));
  // Should find it
  assert(it != end);

  // Search for 2,1
  it = t.find(Entry(e3, e3+2));
  // Should find it
  assert(it != end);

  // Search for 3,2
  it = t.find(Entry(e4, e4+2));
  // Should NOT find it
  assert(it == end);
}
```